# IE 10 problems with jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10

I have some problems with jQuery in IE10.
Some scripts doesn't work in that version of IE.
In others browser (also in oldest IE) everything works fine.
Code of one og them below.

```
jQuery.fn.firma_wpis = function(form,wymag){
  var dur = 350;
  var wymag='1';
  if(this.attr('checked')==true){
    $("#wpis_firma").show(dur);
  }
```

I also added sample code to see if it works, but unfortunately not

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("Works fine");
});
```

This is simple hide show event when user click on the checkbox.
In IE10 Developers Tools I found this error:
**SCRIPT438: Object does not support property or method**

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `if (this.attr('checked')==true)` should probably be `if (this.prop('checked'))`

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause ***"SCRIPT438: Object does not support property or method"***, please provide more context. (unless of course you aren't including jQuery at all)

Comment: Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tempina/2ac6g/
Also doesn't work. This code base on osCommerce.

Answer (score 2):

Try this condition:

```
this.is(':checked')
```

I.e.:

```
jQuery.fn.firma_wpis = function(form,wymag){
  var dur = 350;
  var wymag='1';
  if(this.is(':checked')){
    $("#wpis_firma").show(dur);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be `this` here: `if(this.attr('checked')==true){`.

I think you mean `$(this)`.

In context, `this` refers to the anonymous function being called, not necessarily an instance of jQuery, and thus the `.attr` method may not be available. Wrapping the contextual indicator in a jQuery selector will return an object with the proper methods.

*HOWEVER* it may be caused by jQuery being improperly loaded, or another factor. It would be helpful if you could create and reference a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Actually `this` is a jQuery object, no need to wrap it with `$()`.

Comment: From my experience, `this` and `$(this)` are often not the same.

Comment: inside the body of a plugin, `this` refers to the actual jQuery collection on which the plugin was called, so you don't actually need to wrap `this` into a jQuery object... it would be like calling `$($(this))`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.The scripts are located in different places and not every php file detects jQuery.Because of that I added a link to the jQuery in a specific file, and it works.
I know this is not a perfect solution, but the code is a mess